# How divisible are ripples?

Tags: money-supply, money, ripple, divisibility

How divisible are [ripples](https://ripple.com/) (XRP)? With 100 billion of the currency units being created at system inception one could assume that they are akin to satoshis, but during the operation of the system I found my balance being charged sub-ripple amounts for some operations. How much can one ripple be divided into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XRP are internally represented as an integer number of millionths of a ripple. No term has yet been accepted for naming these units, but some people have (I think jokingly) referred to them as "Jeds".

**Update**: It looks like they will be officially referred to as drops as [you suggested](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=40#p228). A transaction costs 10 drops. There are a million drops in a ripple.